# Pass JavaScript argument to PHP with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I need to be able to send a JavaScript variable to a PHP function. I was able to get it working for hard-coded values such as the code below.

```
<button onclick="submitform()">Click me</button>
<script>
    function submitform(){
      document.write(' <?php send_mail('hello'); ?> ');
    }
</script>

<?php
    function send_mail($subject){
        //$subject => 'hello'
        //Do something with subject
    }
?>
```

However, I cannot replace the hard-coded value with a variable. I would also like to find another way to issue the PHP function call. I believe the solution lies in an ajax request. I cannot find a way to do this with the PHP code directly embedded as it is now. All of the other examples I cannot get to work. If possible, I would appreciate a demo as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using forms:

```
 <form action="send_mail.php" method="post">
         <input type="text"  id="mail" name = "mail">
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Send Mail">
    </form>
```

Then you can access the mail using $_POST["mail"] from the send_mail.php page

Another way to do it is ajax:

```
$.ajax({ url: '/send_mail.php',
         data: {action: 'sendEmail', mymail:$('#mail').val()},
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
                      alert(output);
                  }
});
```

Then in the send_mail.php page you can do:

```
 if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
        $action = $_POST['action'];
    $mail = $_POST['mymail'];

        switch($action) {
            case 'sendEmail' : send_email();break;
            // ...etc...
        }
    }
```

Demo for same page call:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['action'])=='myfunc') {
    echo  "Hello";
}
?>

<form action="?action=myfunc" method="post">
    <input type="text"  id="mail" name = "mail">
    <input id="clickMe" type="submit" value="clickme"/>
```

Comment: I must embed the PHP in the HTML code itself. With the ajax way how can I replace the url with just a `./`? Also do I need any imports for ajax?

Comment: You can use <?php to add your function to the same page and change the url to the same page. Also, I edited the answer to include importing data

Comment: I still cannot get either the form version or the ajax version working on the same page. From what I've gathered online PHP on the same page should be handled with not including the url in the ajax request. That doesn't work and neither does including the actual URL. Can you please include a demo?

Comment: I've added a demo

Comment: I'm still having trouble with getting is all running together. What am I doing wrong here? https://pastebin.com/S5Cnf2Qz

Comment: You can try now the new demo